# Ionic 3: Check if sub-array exists in NavParams.get

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

So, my app gets a response and navCtrl.push's it as an array into another page
let's say the constructor on the ts of that page looks like this

```js
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.id = navParams.get('infoList')[0].id;
    this.name = navParams.get('infoList')[0].full_name;
    this.email = navParams.get('infoList')[0].email;
    this.epmname = navParams.get('infoList')[0].managers[0].full_name;
    this.epmemail = navParams.get('infoList')[0].managers[0].email;
    this.epm2name = navParams.get('infoList')[0].managers[1].full_name;
    this.epm2email = navParams.get('infoList')[0].managers[1].email;
    this.epm3name = navParams.get('infoList')[0].managers[2].full_name;
    this.epm3email = navParams.get('infoList')[0].managers[2].email;
  }
```

Now, the response may not always have a managers sub array or may only have 1 or 2 sub-elements and not 3, How can I perform a check for this? Thanks

UPDATE: this is how a part of my results.html page looks like:

```html
<ion-item-divider color="light">
      Manager Info (Second EPM - if exists):
    </ion-item-divider>
    <ion-item color="none">
      Name: {{epm2name}}
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item color="none">
      Country Code: {{epm2countrycode}}
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item color="none">
      Phone number: {{epm2phone}}
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item color="none">
      Email: {{epm2email}}
    </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really a horrible way to do that. I highly suggest you use a more **object-oriented** pattern here. If you follow that then you can easily check the `null` and etc.

**Note:** I have extracted below example from one of my project.So please adjust it according to your app. If you have any questions feel free to ask it.

**Send**

*my-send-page.ts*

```
goToEditBudget(data: Budget) {
    let dtoBudget = new DtoBudget();
    dtoBudget.budget = data;
    dtoBudget.action = 'edit'
    this.navCtrl.push('AddBudgetPage', { data: dtoBudget });
  }
```

**Retrieved**

*add-budget-page.ts*

```
constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams) {
    let data: DtoBudget = this.navParams.get('data');
    if (data != null) {
      this.data = data.budget;
      this.action = data.action;
    }
  }
```

*DtoBudget.ts*

```
import { Transaction } from './../Transaction';
import { Budget } from './../Budget';

export class DtoBudget {
    budget: Budget;
    action: string;
    transactions: Transaction[]
}
```

Comment: I have added my html code into the post, how can I fix it to not show anything in those slots if null?

Comment: Ok apparently it already does that, Thanks all looks great <3

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :)